# When I adjust the browser really fast, why is there a gap below the photo? (media queries)

Tags: media-queries, enquire.js

[Demo here](http://saratheneale.github.io/enquireMQTest/enquireTest.html)

I use a series of height-based media queries in enquire.js to 'zoom' the picture. When you increase the height of the browser really fast, a big gap is between the picture and the footer. If you increase the height slowly, there isn't a big gap.

This is wrong: 
[image: wrong. happens when height increased fast]

This is right: 
[image: correct- happens when height is increased slowly]

In the console, you can see that several unmatches fire all at the same browser height when the gap happens. Why is that?

Is there something about my implementation that is wrong? Can I use enquire.js to override this behavior somehow?

I have somewhat small query limits. And when I used larger gaps between queries, this problem didn't happen. Ideally, I'd like to keep these small query limits. Here's my code:

```coffeescript
CatZoomHelper = {

  meowZooms: [
    1.70
    1.60
    1.51
    1.41
    1.35
    1.30
    1.25
    1.20
    1.15
    1.10
    1.05
    1
    0.95
    0.90
    0.89
    0.87
    0.83
    0.79
    0.75
    0.72
    0.65
  ]

  registerMediaQueries: (handler) ->
    enquire.register("screen and (min-height: 1220px)", handler(1.70))
    enquire.register("screen and (min-height: 1136px)", handler(1.60))

    enquire.register("screen and (max-height: 1135px)", handler(1.51))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height: 1070px)", handler(1.41))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height: 1010px)", handler(1.35))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  989px)", handler(1.30))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  940px)", handler(1.25))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  925px)", handler(1.20))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  875px)", handler(1.15))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  850px)", handler(1.10))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  830px)", handler(1.05))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  790px)", handler( 1.00))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  745px)", handler(  .95))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  725px)", handler( .90))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  685px)", handler( .89))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  618px)", handler( .83))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  590px)", handler( .79))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  570px)", handler( .75))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  550px)", handler( .72))
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  520px)", handler( .65))
}

handler = (zoom) ->
  zoom: zoom

  MAX_ZOOM: 1.7

  setup: ->

  zooms: CatZoomHelper.meowZooms

  match: ->

    this.zoomIndex = this.zooms.indexOf(this.zoom)
    if this.zoomIndex is -1
      this.zoomIndex = this.zooms[7]
      console.error 'zoomIndex is off'   
    console.log 'MATCH: zoom' + this.zoom + 'window height: ' + window.innerHeight

    $('img').css("height",(689*this.zoom)+"px")

  unmatch: ->
    unmatchZoom;
    if this.zoom is this.MAX_ZOOM
      unmatchZoom = this.zooms[this.zoomIndex + 1]
    else
      unmatchZoom = this.zooms[this.zoomIndex - 1]

    $('img').css("height",(689*unmatchZoom)+"px")

    console.log "UNMATCH from zoom " + this.zoom + "TO " + unmatchZoom + 'window height: ' + window.innerHeight

CatZoomHelper.registerMediaQueries(handler)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround is to

- use more specific media queries so there is not a different behavior
  when shrinking and increasing the size of the browser window.
- get rid of the unmatch function altogether. (fitting in with the philosophy that unmatch is a cleanup function and not the opposite of match)
- register the media queries in a different order.

My register order is now:

```coffeescript
  registerMediaQueries: (handler) ->

    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  520px)", handler(.65));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  550px) and (min-height:  521px)", handler(.72));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  570px) and (min-height:  551px)", handler(.75));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  590px) and (min-height:  571px)", handler(.79));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  618px) and (min-height:  591px)", handler(.83));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  685px) and (min-height:  619px)", handler(.89));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  725px) and (min-height:  686px)", handler(.90));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  745px) and (min-height:  726px)", handler(.95));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  790px) and (min-height:  746px)", handler(1.00));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  830px) and (min-height:  791px)", handler(1.05));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  850px) and (min-height:  831px)", handler(1.10));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  875px) and (min-height:  851px)", handler(1.15));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  925px) and (min-height:  876px)", handler(1.20));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  940px) and (min-height:  926px)", handler(1.25));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height:  989px) and (min-height:  941px)", handler(1.30));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height: 1010px) and (min-height:  990px)", handler(1.35));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height: 1070px) and (min-height:  1011px)", handler(1.41));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height: 1135px) and (min-height:  1071px)", handler(1.51));
    enquire.register("screen and (max-height: 1220px) and (min-height:  1136px)", handler(1.60));
    enquire.register("screen and (min-height: 1221px)", handler(1.70));
```

Solution Demo [here](http://saratheneale.github.io/enquireMQTest/solution.html).

Issues [#80](https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/issues/80) , [#38](https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/issues/38)  , and [#29](https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/issues/29) for the enquire.js project helped to give some insight into this.